# Chartjs and ChartDataLabels does not work in mdb5 pro version 2

Tags: webpack, chart.js, laravel-mix, mdbootstrap

I trying to use Mdbootstrap 5 versions 2 in my project and I install different packages for it. it needs to 'chart.js' and 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels' package and I install them via npm
but I got some errors that can see in the below figure.
I use these version
"chart.js": "^3.7.0",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0". I also use laravel-mix for creating mix version for css and js files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js V3 has a lot of major breaking changes. For one `Chart.plugins` does not exist anymore, you just register and unregister things on the Chart instance directly.

Although I dont know why you would want to globally unregister a plugin. A better option is to not register it at all then. Or register it only on a per chart basis.

Changing `Chartjs.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels)` to `Chartjs.unregister(ChartDataLabels)` will fix your error

Comment: Thanks. I want only use mdb 5. This is part of mdb 5 modules that I got error.   I don't want change anything's. I use Laravel-mix to get single js file.

Comment: Than you can't use chart.js V3, you will need to use version 2.9.4 max and version 1.0.0 of the datalabels plugin